# Why the contains method returns false when trying to pass two identical arrays of Integers

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two objects. Each object is a pair of arrays (A,B) of integers. I have looked on the web on how to proprly implement it, But still return false. As an example: the following code

```
    Example ex=new Example(new Integer[]{0,0,1},new Integer[]{1,0,0});
    Example ex2=new Example(new Integer[]{0,0,1},new Integer[]{1,0,0});
    System.out.println(ex.equals(ex2));
```

return false. While it should be true. I am sure it is something because of the Integer class/autobox wrapping?

```
    class Example{
    Integer[] A;
    Integer[] B;
   // constructor and setters and getters 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getA().hashCode()+getB().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Example)
        {
            Example ex=(Example)obj;
            if(ex.getA().equals(getA())&& ex.getB().equals(getB()))
                return true;
            if(ex.getA().equals(getB())&& ex.getB().equals(getA()))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
      return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.equals(A, ex.A)`

Answer (score 2):

The `equals` method you're using is comparing references, which is basically the same thing as doing `==` between them (or between any other reference types). Both references are considered equal if they point to the same object in memory. Since you're creating two individual arrays of integers, they are two different objects at two different memory locations. That's why you always get `false` as the result.

To compare arrays element-wise, use the `Arrays.equals` method like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Example)
        {
            Example ex=(Example)obj;
            if(Arrays.equals(ex.getA(), getA())&& Arrays.equals(ex.getB(), getB()))
                return true;
            if(Arrays.equals(ex.getA(), getB())&& Arrays.equals(ex.getB(), getA()))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
      return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `.equals()` on two arrays, it will do the same thing as `==`, which is to check if the references are the same. Because they are not, it will return `false`. You want to use [`java.util.Arrays.equals(A, ex.getA())`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)).

Comment: Isn't this should be auto (un)boxing or something? something introduced in JDK 5 ..been long time on Java.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to. Maybe deep equality?